# Age distribution when meeting

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

I have a question regarding Poisson process.

I will tell the story in the context of a player-monster game.

Consider a player who is born at $t=0$. He will win the game if he can survive until $t=1$. Time is continuous. At each instant, he could be stopped by a monster with Poisson rate $\lambda$. Then he enters a fight. The monster could win with probability $p$. If so, the player loses one life.

The player has 2 lives in total. So he can lose only once.

Assume I am one of the monsters. Conditional on I meet the player, can I infer the probability distribution of the player's progress in terms of time $t$? If so, what's that?

If the player is beaten by me this time, what's the probability he will win?

Please let me know if my question is well defined or I miss something important to make it do-able.

Thanks a lot!

^_^

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "Assume I am one of the monsters. Conditional on I meet the player", since in the Poisson description of the game there are no monsters with individual identities. The only way I can translate this into the Poisson description is: "Conditional on the player meeting at least one monster, what is the probability distribution of the age $t$ of the player when meeting a monster uniformly randomly chosen among all monsters the player meets?" Is this what you mean? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think your interpretation is much better. Yes, it is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player meets monsters at the rate $\lambda$, and with probability $p$ they are winning monsters, so the player meets winning monsters at the rate $\lambda p$. We can extend the game up to $t=1$, with monsters appearing after the player's death meeting a dead player. Then, since the Poisson monsters appear uniformly in time, the probability distribution over $t$ that you're looking for is proportional to the probability that the player is still alive at time $t$. This is the probability that he has not yet encountered two winning monsters at rate $\lambda p$, which is $\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}(1+\lambda pt)$. Normalizing over $[0,1]$ yields the probability density

$$
f(t) = \frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}(1+\lambda pt)}{\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-\lambda ps}(1+\lambda ps)\,\mathrm ds}\;.
$$

If the player is beaten by a monster, the probability that he will win is the probability that he hadn't been beaten yet, which is

$$
\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}}{\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}(1+\lambda pt)}=\frac1{1+\lambda pt}\;,
$$

times the probability that he won't be beaten for the rest of the game, which is $\mathrm e^{-\lambda p(1-t)}$. Integrating this product with the density yields

$$
\int_0^1f(t)\frac1{1+\lambda pt}\mathrm e^{-\lambda p(1-t)}\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda p}}{\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-\lambda ps}(1+\lambda ps)\,\mathrm ds}=\frac{\lambda p}{2\mathrm e^{\lambda p}-2-\lambda p}\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a question. Could you explain a little the term $$\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}}{\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}(1+\lambda pt)}=\frac1{1+\lambda pt}$$
for "If the player is beaten by a monster, the probability that he will win is the probability that he hadn't been beaten yet"

Comment: Also, I am not sure about the density you derived. The term $$\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}(1+\lambda pt)$$ is a probability. If we want to compute density, do we need to take derivative?

Comment: @AndyXu: On your first question: The monster is meeting the player alive, so the player has encountered either $0$ or $1$ winning monsters. They arrive at rate $\lambda p$, so the probabilities for the two cases are $p_0=\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}$ and $p_1=\mathrm e^{-\lambda pt}\lambda pt$, respectively. The quotient is the conditional probability $p_0/(p_0+p_1)$.

Comment: @AndyXu: On your second question: No, the density is proportional to that probability. Perhaps it's easier to see this in a simpler example: Imagine that the player always dies at $t=1/2$. Then monsters arriving uniformly randomly meet the player alive with probability $1$ if $t\lt1/2$ and with probability $0$ if $t\gt1/2$. The density for the age distribution you're looking for is proportional to this probability; it is this probability divided by its integral, which is $1/2$, so it's $2$ for $t\lt1/2$ and $0$ for $t\gt1/2$. (Differentiating would yield $0$ everywhere except at $t=1/2$.)

Comment: @AndyXu: To make sense of the apparent weirdness of a density being given by a probability, note that we already have a density, namely the constant density of the arriving Poisson monsters, and we're conditionalizing it on the player being alive. So we're basically applying Bayes' theorem in the form

$$
f(t\mid\text{alive})=\frac{f(t)p(\text{alive}\mid t)}{p(\text{alive})}\;,
$$

and because $f(t)\equiv1$, the density is determined entirely by the probabilities.

Comment: @AndyXu: On the comment you posted and then deleted, about the question arising because of my comment under the question: Yes, I noticed that my answer ended up fitting better with your original formulation than with my attempt at making it precise :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realize that the biggest problem of my question is that I failed to define an unconditional time distribution $f(t)$. 

Although player meets monster with rate $\lambda$, we have no idea how the monster meets the player. Then you assume that it is uniformly distributed - If player never die during $[0,1]$, then the time distribution if $U[0,1]$. Is it what your assumption means?

Comment: @AndyXu: Yes -- but I don't think it's an additional assumption; I think it's implied by my rigorous formulation in the comment under the question. Since the Poisson monsters are uniform in time, uniformly randomly choosing a monster among the monsters that the player meets alive is equivalent to conditionalizing the constant density on the player being alive.

Comment: I see. Indeed, the Poisson birth of Monster is equivalent to constant density corresponding to time. Thanks so much for the help!